# optimise PuTTY on Windows 7 for huge & steady packet loss

Tags: packet-loss

There's a 25% packet loss between my connection and that of my server, and my server company doesn't want to do anything about it, since it's at one of their peers, not directly on their infrastructure. https://gist.github.com/cnst/5289192

```
 3.|-- hos-bb2.juniper4.rz2.hetzner.de 100 100 0.0% 2.7 3.3 4.9 59.7 8.5
4.|-- r1nue1.core.init7.net 100 100 0.0% 2.8 4.5 5.3 14.0 3.4
5.|-- r1nue2.core.init7.net 100 100 0.0% 2.9 4.4 5.3 14.2 3.8
6.|-- r1fra2.core.init7.net 100 100 0.0% 5.7 9.0 9.8 17.7 4.3
7.|-- r1fra1.core.init7.net 100 100 0.0% 5.8 8.0 8.7 17.1 3.7
8.|-- xe-4-2-2.fra23.ip4.tinet.net 100 57 43.0% 10.2 11.9 12.5 47.9 5.9
9.|-- xe-3-0-0.dal33.ip4.tinet.net 100 58 42.0% 140.2 144.4 144.9 200.8 12.9
10.|-- cox-gw.ip4.tinet.net 100 60 40.0% 140.4 143.3 143.5 190.9 9.0
11.|-- mtc3dsrj01-ae1.0.rd.ok.cox.net 100 58 42.0% 142.3 145.8 146.1 187.7 9.4
```

Very few routes are affected, but, apparently, the connection at my home is one of those that is very noticeable affected.

My ssh is damn slow due to this huge packet loss.  Is there any way to speed it up?  Basically, in this specific situation, the **latency is ALWAYS below 200ms**.

**Is there a way to ensure retransmissions from the server, and the client, when nothing has happened within 200ms?**

Server runs OpenBSD; client runs Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) would be *perfect* for this, other than not having a windows client (outside cygwin) - its a protocol specifically designed to handle packet loss and high latency and still remain usable. Its not exactly what you want, so, if you want to alter the scope of the question, let me know, and I'll post this as an answer

Comment: Does mosh handle huge packet loss when no latency issues are present?

Comment: Its supposed to. It even handles disconnecting, switching internet connections, and reconnecting

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, sounds interesting, and I think I've been recommended mosh before, but it doesn't list OpenBSD as supported (plus Windows 7 is not natively supported, either)

Comment: There's no package for it. It *should* however compile on openbsd I think